# input to command prompt from perl script

Tags: perl, input, command, prompt

How to supply input to command prompt from perl script. For example selecting an option from command prompt supplying username or password to command prompt etc..I think i am clear enough.

Comment: Just to be totally clear, do you want to prompt the user via the perl script or answer an external prompt given to you via a perl script?

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $input = <STDIN>;

chomp($input);

print "You wrote: $input\n";
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. I am not saying getting input which is given to the command prompt rather giving input to command prompt from my script. For example supplying username or password from script whenever required without manually entering in the command line.

Comment: You can write to STDOUT but I'd ask what you're trying to do, because there's probably a CPAN module that will handle the authentication for you. The most abstract is [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) but there's probably something more specific. To print to STDOUT simply do: `print STDOUT $output;`

Answer (score 0):

See [`Term::Prompt`](http://metacpan.org/module/Term%3a%3aPrompt), [`Term::UI`](http://metacpan.org/module/Term%3a%3aUI), [`IO::Prompt`](http://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aPrompt), [`IO::Prompter`](http://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aPrompter), [`IO::Prompt::Tiny`](http://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aPrompt%3a%3aTiny) modules, and all that.

Answer (score 0):

And if you're looking for options rather than the user typing in something, consider [GetOpt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/~jv/Getopt-Long/lib/Getopt/Long.pm).